# Can't get value from $scope from Jquery to Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello Guys I am learner in AngularJS. I have problem with this. I want to ask you why it doesn't show me data to HTML page. When I press F12, it doesn't show me any errors...Why I can't set data for variable $scope=students ?
Could someone explain to me why ? Thanks a lot :)

```
 <div id="angularController" data-ng-controller="firstCtrl" data-ng-app="app">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            University
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Gender
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students">
                        <td>
                            {{student.id}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{student.name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{student.university}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{student.gender}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
            var str;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                str = '{"id":"1","name":"Nang Thang Hai","university":"Hutech University","gender":"true"},{"id":"2","name":"Gio Thang Chin","university":"Foreign Trade University","gender":"false"}';
                angular.element('#angularController').controller().doSomthing(str);
                //angular.element('#angularController').controller()
            });
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope) {           
                //$scope.students = json = $.parseJSON('[' + str + ']');
                $scope.doSomthing = function (str) {
                    json = $.parseJSON('[' + str + ']');                    
                     alert(json[0].name);// it shows data here:Bui Vuong Khanh
                $scope.students = json;//is it right ?
                };
                return {
                    doSomthing: $scope.doSomthing
                };

            });
</script>
```

Comment: why do you want to call jQuery with angularjs.... don't mix those two unless there is no other way

Comment: Thank you. But this is my issue when I work in the company. I use this example to show my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll never recommend it if possible, but here the problem is when you are updating the scope values from outside of the digest cycle, angularjs will not run the watches associated with the scope properties, so the UI and other updates done by angular watches will not happen.

One possible solution is to call [Scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) which will help to execute angular life cycle methods.

```
var str;
$(document).ready(function () {
    str = '{"id":"1","name":"Nang Thang Hai","university":"Hutech University","gender":"true"},{"id":"2","name":"Gio Thang Chin","university":"Foreign Trade University","gender":"false"}';
    angular.element('#angularController').controller().doSomthing(str);
    angular.element('#angularController').scope().$apply();
    //angular.element('#angularController').controller()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0awfmc41/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.students = JSON.parse(str);
```

This should be the way. Don't mix up jQuery with AngularJS. Infact you should try to use the least amount of jquery with AngularJS

Comment: Thank you. This is the problem when I work in the company. I use that example to show you my issue. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Did the answer help you? If it did then mark it as correct otherwise clearly state your problem in a comment. And I don't understand your comment clearly. Elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

like @Arun P Johny said don't mix the library. but if you really have to use both of them try using

```
$.noConflict();
```

and use the jquery code. that might be an option for your code to work.Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning AngularJS, don't try to mix it with jquery. A simple solution without jquery

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope) {
     var str = '{"id":"1","name":"Nang Thang Hai","university":"Hutech University","gender":"true"},{"id":"2","name":"Gio Thang Chin","university":"Foreign Trade University","gender":"false"}';

     $scope.doSomething = function (str) {
         json = JSON.parse('[' + str + ']');
         $scope.students = json;
     };

     $scope.doSomething(str);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="angularController" ng-controller="firstCtrl" ng-app="app">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>University</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="student in students">
                <td>{{student.id}}</td>
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td>{{student.university}}</td>
                <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dw8o0bho/2/

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't want to mix with Jquery. But this is the problem when I work in the company. I use that example to show you my issue. Anyway thanks a lot.